# how to use jira-python to create issue

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

i filed up a simple script to test sending issues to jira via python,

```
from jira import JIRA

jira_options={'server': 'https://jira.baidu.com', 'verify': False}

jira=JIRA(options=jira_options,basic_auth=('testuser','passw0rd'))

new_issue = jira.create_issue(project={'key': 'test'}, summary='New issue from jira-python',   description='Look into this one', issuetype={'name': 'Bug'})
```

but got the error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:821: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    jira=JIRA(options=jira_options,basic_auth=('testuser','passw0rd'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 317, in __init__
    si = self.server_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 1771, in server_info
    j = self._get_json('serverInfo')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 2172, in _get_json
    r = self._session.get(url, params=params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 150, in get
    return self.__verb('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 146, in __verb
    raise_on_error(response, verb=verb, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 56, in raise_on_error
    r.status_code, error, r.url, request=request, response=r, **kwargs)
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: <exception str() failed>
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: i tried many times, all started popping out error from this line: \n JIRA(options=jira_options,basic_auth=('testuser','passw0rd'))

Comment: i tried importing JIRA from both jira & jira.client libraries, both turned out same error...

Comment: i tried to answer this question but why every time i submitted my answer it doesn't show?

Comment: i should keep a note here that the problem has been found: the captcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know i am late but which python version you are using? For python 3 the import works like this for me.
Try this:

```
    import jira.client
    from jira.client import JIRA
```

Comment: The poster uses Python 2.7, you can see it in the first line of the reported error in the question

Comment: thanks Umair, seems i forgot to note here: it turned out that it was the captcha.... after i completed the captcha verification, it worked fine. i don't quite remember the python version though.